# Is there any way to record screen using flash?

Tags: flash, screen, record

I want to write a website which have functions to record user's screen, and allow user to upload it.

Is there any api for flash to record the screen?

Many thanks!

Comment: It IS possible for AIR applications, but only to record the screenspace occupied by the application itself. I doubt that it is possible for Flex applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not such a thing - Adobe wouldn't allow such a security hole.

The upload part is simple, as for getting a screenshot I'd say ask the user to click on his "Print Screen" (with Alt maybe, test yourself the combination - it has difference!).

Then the user goes to Paint, pastes the image and saves it.

Then upload to you.